Count the Minimum Operations of making an array's all subarrays' sum non-negative.
I have encountered an question in interview. Given an array arr of n integers, make the array positive with the following operation: In one operation, select integers i (0 ≤ i < n) and x (-10^18 ≤ x ≤ 10^18) and change arr[i] to x.
An array is positive when the sum of each subarray of length greater than 1 is non-negative. More formally, after the operations, the following condition should hold for all values of l and r: $$\sum_{i=l}^{r} \text{arr}[i] \geq 0,  0 \leq l < r < n$$
Determine the minimum number of operations required to make the array positive.
I know that every time the best way to do is change the number into 10e18. And if any subarray with length 2 and 3 have positive sum, then any subarray can be divided into the composition of subarrays with length 2 or 3.
My attempt to pursue this problem is constructing a 2 dimensional dynamic programming matrix, with dp[i][j] denotes the minimum number operations needed for making subarray arr[i:j] satisfied the conditions. But it seems hard to find the recurrence formula. So I stuck here.
